# Pandas Python matching ID to address using Google Maps Directions API

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

Using Pandas for Python, I have a dataframe (df) with a list of unique ID's, routes, and addresses. It looks something like this:

```html
<table>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Route</th>
<th>Address</th>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>123 Sesame Street</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>55 Park Ave</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>77 Olive Blvd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>DEF</td>
<td>65 Louis Street</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>DEF</td>
<td>23 Brown Ave</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>XYZ</td>
<td>123 Sesame Street</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to run each route through Google Maps Directions and return the most efficient sequence to run the route in and assign the mileage for each address from the previous address while not losing that unique ID. I need to get the mileage for that ID basically.

I am running into a problem matching the addresses in my dataframe to the address that Google Maps returns. So for instance, in my dataframe the address may say something like:

```
123 SESAME ST, SAINT LOUIS, 63110
```

Meanwhile, Google Maps may return it as an address of:

```
123 Sesame Street, St. Louis, MO 63110
```

Matching up the thousands of addresses that way will be very difficult as I am not going to be able to predict all of the unique scenarios for the addresses, so ideally I would assign the ID to the address. I can create a dictionary for them so each address is matched to its ID in the dictionary, but is there a way to send that ID to Google Maps so it returns that to me along with the address?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it doing a round about way. I just saved the waypoint from Google Maps results and zipped it with the addresses I submitted so it would be a new list of tuples that included addresses and sequence.